# React Native onHostDestroy()

Tags: android, react-native

I have a base activity which contains the `reactInstanceManager`. All further activities are extending this one. My problem is that I have too many activity instances sticking around in the memory, leaking it. I thought that `reactInstanceManager` is a SINGLETON, but it isn't true.

Could someone explain to me, how can I destroy a `reactInstanceManager`, when an activity exited (launching another activity) ?

I tried to call `onHostDestroy()` in `onDestroy()`, but it's causing a crash.

Comment: I am in the exact same boat as you, have you find any workaround for this problem?

Comment: have you seen my answer below?
Did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions was to implement the onDestroy() in the base activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this` in `removeReactInstanceEventListener(this)`? According to the docs, it's expecting a `ReactInstanceEventListerner` object.